# I renamed my project months ago, and I'm still seeing "com.example.myproject" coming up in logcat. How do I fix this once and for all?

Tags: android, android-studio

My project started out as `com.example.myproject`.  Months ago, I refactor>renamed the project to `com.mycompany.myproject`.

Yet - I am still frequently seeing `com.example.myproject` showing up in log cat.  When I build my project, it says `building com.example.--`.

My manifest is properly configured to use the new name:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mycompany.myproject"
...
```

Project directory structure is:

```
MyProject
...app
......src
.........main
............java
...............com.mycompany.myproject
```

Every class has `package com.mycompany.myproject` at the top. I can find no traces of `com.example` anywhere in my entire project.

I am at a loss.  How do I get rid of this?  It's driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning and rebuilding your project.

Also, sometimes if you have the old build installed on your test device, Eclipse picks up the old package name. Try uninstalling the old build, and then reinstall the build with the updated package name.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your project structure looks like a gradle one. Have a look at your `build.gradle`.

Use the search function to search (Ctrl + shift + f) for the old (unwanted) name.